# User permissions on WordPress blog

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, password-protection

I'm looking for a suggestion on how to set up the user permissions on wordpress plugin. For Example: I've Contact Form 7 plugin, when a author signing in to his account, he can see the plugin and upon clicking on it he can easily see the shortcodes. I want all author have access just the "Posts" item from wordpress admin panel (left navigation), so that they can just post article or nothing else.

Is it possible? How can i do that? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following code to your `wp-config.php`.

```
/** Allow only admins to see contact form 7 settings in admin panel */

define( 'WPCF7_ADMIN_READ_CAPABILITY', 'manage_options' );

define( 'WPCF7_ADMIN_READ_WRITE_CAPABILITY', 'manage_options' );
```

This will allow only admin to access `Contact Form 7` menu in the `Dashboard`.
Do not forget add the above code just after the below code in `wp-config.php`. Otherwise it will not work.

```
/** The Database Collate type. Don't change this if in doubt. */

define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress adminimize plugin to set the permissions to your desired parts in the admin. It is very effective and fulfill all your needs. You can find it from here : https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/